# Devspace deploy error: pullSecrets[0].registry: cannot be empty

Tags: python, django, docker, kubernetes, devspace

I'm studying how to deploy a django application with kubernetes, I found [this tutorial](https://devspace.cloud/blog/2019/10/18/deploy-django-to-kubernetes), which explains about the Devspace tool, so that following the tutorial just like it returns me a message that I can't solve.
the message is this:
[image]

returns only this `[fatal]  pullSecrets[0].registry: cannot be empty`

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevSpace maintainer here. Check your devspace.yaml and you'll see that there is a `pullSecrets` section defined and the first entry in this section has `registry` either not defined or empty string.

To fix this, you can either remove the entire `pullSecrets` or provide a valid registry hostname + username and password. For the username and especially for the password, you should use variables such as `${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}` and then set them via environment variables in your terminal or let DevSpace set them via `devspace set var REGISTRY_PASSWORD=xxx` etc.

Answer (score 0):

First thing in your setup at very first you missed **two** steps

in which it's asking about the **docker registry** and **username** & authentication.

If you will pass the detail you won't face any issue and secret will get created automatically.

You have to set the value for pull **secret** to `true`

```
createPullSecret: true
```

pull seceret is used by Kubernetes config when you have to fetch the container (docker) image from the private container repository for example **private docker repository**.

If your config pull already exist but you have not created it you can create it manually by providing a few details

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry my-pull-secret --docker-server=[REGISTRY_URL] --docker-username=[REGISTRY_USERNAME] --docker-password=[REGISTRY_PASSWORD] --docker-email=[YOUR_EMAIL]
```

Read more at : https://devspace.cloud/docs/v3.5.18/image-building/registries/pull-secrets

There is same issue reported previously : https://github.com/loft-sh/devspace/issues/1317

Comment: thanks for the help, but that didn't solve it, i created it using the command and the error continues, i added a few more answers specifying what i did

Comment: try restarting the container if you have created the secret which proper name which is mentioned in deployment.